# NOT LIKE statement in Hive

Tags: mysql, hive

In `mysql` I am using the following statement to find tables `not like` in a database.

```
show tables where `Tables_in_db` not like '%_table'
```

I am able to use the statement like below to find tables `like` in hive

```
show tables like '*table'
```

But unable to use the `not like` statement

```
show tables where `Tables_in_db` not like '*_table'
```

Is there an equivalent for this statement in `Hive`.

Comment: Query the metastore

Comment: @DuduMarkovitz we don't have `hive` metastore

Comment: Off course you do. Where do you think the information displayed by `show tables` is taken for?. Check the parameter `javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The below one can be used:

In SQL:

```
select * from tableName where columnName not like '%something%';
```

In Hive:

```
select * from tableName where not (columnName like '%something%');
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: The original question seems to be about using `not like` in Hive `show tables` statements, not `select` statements. The original point stands, I think: `show tables like 'abc'` works, but `show tables not like 'abc'` does not. Any thoughts on this?

Comment: as commented by Chris this is not a correct answer to the question