# how to use not like in show tables in hive?

Tags: hadoop, hive

I'm trying to get all tables in a database which are not like specific key words.
i'm able to use like function but not able to use not like in show tables

```
 show tables like '*student*';
```

above query is working

```
show tables not like '*student*'
 and '*employee*';
```

second query is not working.

can some one help me with the above query and tell me why it is not working

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NOT LIKE statement in Hive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43926762/not-like-statement-in-hive)

Comment: @SkandaShastry i need to get table names from a db. not column names from particular table.

``` show tables not like '*student' or '*employee';```  i'm looking for student and employee are part of table names not column names

Answer (score 0):

You should query your Hive metastore to support this.

Otherwise, try to pipe the output to grep

```
hive -e "show tables" | grep -v student
```